# Flutter : Showing Event from API to Table Calendar

Tags: flutter, api, dart, calendar

I want to show Calendar and including event, the event already exists from API. I searching plugin fit to my case and I found Table Calendar Plugin.
I hope anyone can give me an answer on how to show _events to my API. Thank you. And this is the [example value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W02UJ.png) from my API

result I want form the api :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxqOf.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to know what i need to put in eventLoader to get result like in th e picture